# Is there a decent GUI for Amazon Route 53?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Because frankly it's a bit tricky without...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unofficial GUI: [github.com/zen4ever/route53manager](https://github.com/zen4ever/route53manager)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Ylastic](http://ylastic.com/) for managing my route 53. It is pay for, but it's the best route 53 interface I've come across. And no, I don't pay merely for route 53, I was a subscriber before 53 came out (i.e. it's not worth it just to manage that).

Answer (score 2):

AWS management console supports it since Nov/16/2011, [**reference**](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/11/aws-management-console-now-supports-amazon-route-53.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure they will eventually add it to the web control console, but for now I don't think there is. You could create a wrapper if you have common actions you need to simplify for your usage, but in general DNS is pretty simple when you understand it, and it's probably not recommended to run your own DNS if you don't because so much depends on it being done just right.